# ¿Cómo modificar el Ancho para Lista desplegable(select) y sus Option?

Tags: html5, css, lista, select2, scroll

Tengo un problema con una lista desplegable, cada `<option>` tiene demasiada información y supera el ancho de la pantalla. Me gustaría que se "acomode" en tres renglones la información por cada `<option>`. O por lo menos, que se me active el scroll, porque la única forma que puedo visualizar la información: disminuyendo el zoom del navegador.

Comment: Anexa una captura de como se muestra y el código de como lo tienes declarado así obtendrás una mejor respuesta.

Comment: Agrega el código que actualmente tienes.

Answer (score 1):

En Base a la respuesta de @Alfonso Carrasco.
En su código no anexa las librerías de select2, pues las anexo y le hice otro cambio mas le quite el CSS que tenia y puse:

```js
$("select").select2({
    width:'100%'
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select>
<option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam sed leo quis dignissim. Nunc porta molestie suscipit. Integer id aliquam eros. Integer lobortis risus semper, convallis arcu vitae, venenatis libero. Fusce non commodo quam. Pellentesque a viverra ante. Etiam at dignissim felis, at lobortis turpis.</option>
  <option>Vivamus ut elit ac tortor rhoncus mollis quis at leo. Vestibulum suscipit tincidunt metus ac aliquet. Donec ultricies odio laoreet consequat elementum. Integer diam ipsum, condimentum eu posuere ac, consequat quis velit. Pellentesque euismod orci vel iaculis condimentum. </option>
  <option> Maecenas id velit molestie, efficitur dolor vel, condimentum turpis. Etiam vel dolor vel justo posuere volutpat. Quisque facilisis, sapien ut blandit posuere, massa nulla imperdiet orci, sit amet tincidunt nisl arcu sollicitudin sem. Morbi vel nisl a dolor tincidunt aliquam.</option>
  <option>Aliquam tellus metus, fermentum eget urna nec, vestibulum condimentum lacus. Nunc felis leo, euismod eget condimentum a, feugiat quis tellus.</option>
  <option> Maecenas id velit molestie, efficitur dolor vel, condimentum turpis. Etiam vel dolor vel justo posuere volutpat. Quisque facilisis, sapien ut blandit posuere, massa nulla imperdiet orci, sit amet tincidunt nisl arcu sollicitudin sem. Morbi vel nisl a dolor tincidunt aliquam.</option>
  <option>Mauris posuere ligula ac nisl laoreet ultricies. Mauris molestie sed nisi et ultrices. Integer feugiat in diam in posuere. Vestibulum a tempus tellus, sed faucibus dui.</option>
</select>
```

Me imagino que en base así quieres que se visualice.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, por la rapidez con que necesitaba la solucion lo que hice fue agregar un textarea readonly y la opcion que se selecciona, se muestra toda la informacion en el ya dicho con ajax, es que en verdad era mucha informacion y creo que esa era como la mas estetica, aunque mi idea principal era hacer un tipo de ventana modal donde se vieran todas las opciones y se pudieran leer con detenimiento, pero todavia me falta aprender  :) mucho. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @ManuelMosquera Puedes publicar tu respuesta eso seria ayuda para otros a futuro, y como sugerencia si quieres una respuesta mas especifica de un error intenta poner el código donde se produce así te darán soluciones más acertadas a tu problema

Answer (score 0):

Creo que he captado un poco la idea, esta es mi respuesta a tu pregunta, todo se basa en el manejo del `CSS`, te dejo el código para su análisis.

1. Debes agregar la propiedad `multiple` a tu menú `select`. `<select multiple> </select>` *(espero no resulte incoveniente)*

Acá te dejo algo de código mas especifico.

```css
select {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
option{ /*es aquí donde esta todo el desarrollo principal*/
word-wrap: break-word; /* Declara que el texto deberá ser Wrap Break en */Word. 
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* lo mismo que lo anterior pero para Firefox*/
  white-space: pre-wrap;  /* lo mismo que lo anterior pero para el resto de los navegadores.*/
  width:300px; /*Se establece un ancho en especifico*/
}
select option:nth-child(odd){
background: lightcyan; /*Solo para darle estilo de fondo a los child en odd*/
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
<option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur aliquam sed leo quis dignissim. Nunc porta molestie suscipit. Integer id aliquam eros. Integer lobortis risus semper, convallis arcu vitae, venenatis libero. Fusce non commodo quam. Pellentesque a viverra ante. Etiam at dignissim felis, at lobortis turpis.</option>
  <option>Vivamus ut elit ac tortor rhoncus mollis quis at leo. Vestibulum suscipit tincidunt metus ac aliquet. Donec ultricies odio laoreet consequat elementum. Integer diam ipsum, condimentum eu posuere ac, consequat quis velit. Pellentesque euismod orci vel iaculis condimentum. </option>
  <option> Maecenas id velit molestie, efficitur dolor vel, condimentum turpis. Etiam vel dolor vel justo posuere volutpat. Quisque facilisis, sapien ut blandit posuere, massa nulla imperdiet orci, sit amet tincidunt nisl arcu sollicitudin sem. Morbi vel nisl a dolor tincidunt aliquam.</option>
  <option>Aliquam tellus metus, fermentum eget urna nec, vestibulum condimentum lacus. Nunc felis leo, euismod eget condimentum a, feugiat quis tellus.</option>
  <option> Maecenas id velit molestie, efficitur dolor vel, condimentum turpis. Etiam vel dolor vel justo posuere volutpat. Quisque facilisis, sapien ut blandit posuere, massa nulla imperdiet orci, sit amet tincidunt nisl arcu sollicitudin sem. Morbi vel nisl a dolor tincidunt aliquam.</option>
  <option>Mauris posuere ligula ac nisl laoreet ultricies. Mauris molestie sed nisi et ultrices. Integer feugiat in diam in posuere. Vestibulum a tempus tellus, sed faucibus dui.</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tienes razón blonfu, no había notado ese detalle... Agregue los comments despues de verificar la funcionalidad. Gracias por el detalle.